# Regex find respective match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm Trying to get the respective StartSession with your EndSession

the string (https://regex101.com/r/kP2bQ4/3):

```
<span class="QuellonStartSession">FirstSession</span><span class="QuellonStartSession">SecondSession</span>SomeContent<span class="QuellonEndSession">EndSecondSession</span>SomeContent...<span class="QuellonEndSession">EndFirstSession</span> ....Content...<span class="QuellonStartSession">SomeSession</span>Content<span class="QuellonEndSession">EndSomeSession</span>
```

Above i have some `QuellonStartSession` and `QuellonEndSession`, the problem occurs when i have some `StartSession`  which is already open, i need to take the respective (start - end). In the example the `FirstSession` needs to get `EndFirstSession` and his content

Comment: Seriously? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/133203

Comment: If you are dealing with HTML, you might want to consider using an actual HTML parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as opposed to a regular expression.

Comment: Well, you might want to study a [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970). However, it won't help if you have nested tags.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, thats all i need